# Heroku Deploy Gets Stuck

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

When I try to deploy to Heroku, it gets stuck at the following line:

```
Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
```

This has been occurring throughout the day. **It gets stuck here for more than 20 minutes** (after that I wait no longer and close the process and try again - with no success).

I have checked my upload speed and it seems fine.

I have not changed any configurations, so I am not sure why it is like this today (it's worked well before), nor have I added any additional dependencies for it to install.

I found this question, which seems similar, but it's for Ruby on Rails, and I have a Python app. [Heroku push hanging on "fetching gem metadata from rubygems" with no errors or trace of any kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059808/heroku-push-hanging-on-fetching-gem-metadata-from-rubygems-with-no-errors-or-t)

**What steps can I take to stop this from happening? Is there any way to Python-ize the solution from the above question?**

Is there a way to skip this step temporarily since I am not adding dependencies anyways?

Comment: Mini-question: does anyone know how to contact Heroku Support with a free account?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550219/git-push-slug-compilation-hangs

Comment: I guess it is. I did search SO and Google before coming here though and I did not see it, well at least it's not just me! :)

Comment: The other asker's heroku request closes after 15 mins and then it works! I wish mine did that, mine doesn't even close (once, I've left it for an hour before - but it still didn't work)

Comment: @GangstaGraham This is happening to me as of right now, it was working perfectly fine a few hours ago. I'm guessing it's a Heroku issue.

Comment: i am having same issues

Comment: its working as of now